# How to comply official android Calendar app from downloaded source?

Tags: android, calendar, open-source, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I've recently downloaded the source-code of the official android jellybean calendar app:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/+/jb-mr2.0-release

I've imported the code to eclipse, but I can't comply it because a lot of packages are missing like

- com.android.datetimepicker.date
- com.android.colorpicker
- com.android.ex.chips
- com.android.calendarcommon2
- etc...

What am I doing wrong? Am i supposed to search and hunt for all the packages and add them manually?

**EDIT::**

Now I told that it's built against the whole OS not just the SDK, so my new question is how to add the whole OS to the eclipse project to make the app work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Most of those apps are not designed to be built using solely the Android SDK. They are designed to be built as part of a full compile of the OS.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. So is there an easy way to make it work somehow? (Like downloading and adding a library or something like that)

Comment: @AdamToth: "So is there an easy way to make it work somehow?" -- not for any conventional definition of "easy". Some of that stuff you may be able to find elsewhere and copy into the project to resolve the references. But there's likely to be some things that you cannot readily disconnect from the rest of the OS, in which case you will either need to rip out the features that depend on that stuff, or come up with some other workaround. Or, if your objective is to build a ROM mod or something, just download and build the whole OS.